# Montserrat Font not working with font weight with tailwind css in my Next App

Tags: css, fonts, tailwind-css, next.js13

When I use Montserrat Font, defined in my Tailwind CSS config file as Sans, I cannot use font-weight when I use the font-light class. It doesn't render the lighter font.

[picture of the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhW3Q.png)
here the second line is in Montserrat and I am unable to use font weight.

you can refer to my github for the code https://github.com/dipesh2508/health-optima

here is the config file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
      colors: {
        'primary': '#A855F7',
        'secondary': '#115E59',
        'background': '#FFFBEB',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
        serif: ['PT Serif', 'serif']
      },
      boxShadow: {
        "custom": '0px 25px 50px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) ',
      },
      
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate"), 'prettier-plugin-tailwindcss'],
}
```

Now take a look at the hero section where I use it

```
<section className='min-h-screen'>
            <video
                muted
                loop
                autoPlay
                className="absolute top-12 left-0 min-w-full min-h-full -z-50 object-cover"
            >
                <source src='/video/bgVideo.mp4' type="video/mp4" />
                <source src='/video/bgVideo.mp4' type="video/ogg" />
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>

            <div className=" bg-black opacity-80 w-full min-h-[99vh] md:min-h-[122vh] absolute top-0 left-0 -z-40"></div>
            <div className=" w-full top-0 px-0 flex min-h-[99vh] md:min-h-[120vh] -mt-24 -z-30 flex-col items-center justify-center">
                <div className="w-[90%] m-auto flex flex-col items-center gap-10">
                    <h1 className="font-serif -z-20 text-center text-2xl md:text-4xl lg:text-7xl leading-loose text-white">
                        Empower Your Wellness  Journey <br /> with <span className="text-primary">Health Optima</span>
                    </h1>
                    <h3 className="text-white text-lg text-center md:text-3xl font-sans font-thin">Your Ultimate Health and Wellness Companion</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tailwind did the same thing to me when I wanted to import a Google font, when using Next and wanting to use a font it has its own rules

you must go to layout.tsx in app folder an then import the font there, but first remove the import from talwind all config

---

in layout.tsx

```html
import { Montserrat } from 'next/font/google'
```

Below the import you must enter

```html
const montserrat = Montserrat({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  style: ['normal', 'italic'...etc],
  weight: ['400', '700'...etc],
})
```

and then you make sure that the HTML tag below looks like this

```html
<html lang="en" className={monserrat.className}>
```